# How to read text file into a 2D array - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io, multidimensional-array

I am new to C++ and having some trouble with reading a text file into the 2D array. I am creating a puzzle game. Text file contains as follows:

3
A ? B
C D E
F G H

Number 3 on top of the text file is the size of the board that I have to create and rest is for the puzzle.

Here is my code that I attempted, any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>


using name space std;

#ifndef BOARD_H
#define BOARD_H

ifstream fin("boardgame.txt");        // Input file

class Board {
private:
int SIZE;         //Board size
char **b;         //2D Array

public:
        Board();                    //Constructor
       ~Board();                    //Destructor
        void readFile();            //Function to read the file

 }; //Board

Board::Board (){

fin>>SIZE;       //Professor specifically asked to read the board size in the  constructor
readFile();

 }
   Board::~Board(){

 // Will create this later

 }
void Board::readFile(){

    cout<<"SIZE is: "<<SIZE<<endl;
    while(!fin.eof()){

        for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
            for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
               fin>>b[row][col];
            }
        }

    }


    for (int row = 0; row < SIZE; row++){
        for (int col = 0; col < SIZE; col++){
            cout<<b[row][col]<<endl;
        }
    } // For testing only.
}// ReadFile

 #endif
```

I am on the right track?

Comment: Have you tried the code? What is the problem?

Comment: Having `fin` as a global is a poor idea. And `while(!fin.eof())` is a recipe for reading an entire row of invalid data. `using name space std;` isn't a valid `using namespace` directive. Putting all of this in a *header* file is going to bite you. So is the *problem* that this doesn't compile? Try addressing each error as it is presented by your compiler.

Comment: You are asking our opinion on your own code. And I think this site is not built for that. Please excessively describe why you think you have any problem with your code.

Comment: @I19 yes, I have tried my code and it crashes once it hits the while(!fin.eof()).

Comment: I was successfully able to read the size but can't read the other characters from the text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array is only a pointer, with no space. You should add a member function to alocate space to that pointer with malloc. Size is passed through arguments. Once you read file and get the size in main function, invoke the new member function to give your array right size. Also, in destructor, you should free the pointer.

Comment: Thank you very much! definitely helped!

Answer (score 0):

you haven't initialize the 2D array. The best way is to initialize the 2D array(new) in constructor, and release in deconstructor. And all the read action should be include in the readFile function. Don't make the ifstream as a global, make the filename as a attribute of the readFile function.